# Error en orden SQL: Delete where id in list

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando borrar las filas de una tabla que corresponden a los id (varchar) '938110842071146496', '938110904666853378', '938195226333777920', '938309442671665152', '938777508123734017'

Para ello utilizo la siguiente orden SQL:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN ('938110842071146496', '938110904666853378', '938195226333777920', '938309442671665152', '938777508123734017')
```

Pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

> #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'WHERE id IN
>   ('938110842071146496', '938110904666853378', '9381952263337779' en la
>   linea 1

¿Alguien sabe que falla?

Comment: Tienes que poner el nombre de la tabla en table, Pedro.

Comment: Tu respuesta es obvia y ya lo había tenido en cuenta. El fallo debe estar en otro lugar.

Comment: podrias dar mas informacion de tu campo id (tipo/tamaño) ya que en la sentencia no hay ningun error. Si creas la sentencia dinamicamente tambien podrias poner esa parte del codigo. Saludos.

Comment: @Pedro la respuesta no es obvia.. eso es lo que escribiste en la pregunta. por favor, hay gente tratando de ayudarte, y no, no es obvio si no dijiste que lo probaste.

Answer (score 0):

Tu Query esta bien, como están las columnas de tu tabla?

```
DELETE from table WHERE id IN ("1","2","3",...,"254");
```

Ahora que si tus columnas son numericas intenta esto

```
DELETE from tablename WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 254;

DELETE from tablename WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 254 AND id<>10;
```

Comment: Esto realmente no responde la pregunta, porque basicamente no estas agregando informacion nueva. OP dijo que sus columnas son varchar asi que la segunda parte no tiene sentido. SALVO, que tu respuesta sean las comillas dobles (en lugar de las simples). Si ese es el caso, podrias aclararlo bien en la respuesta?

Comment: Que sentido tiene agregar data? si lo que quiere es eliminarlo

Comment: Digo que no estas agregando nada que no haya dicho OP en su pregunta...

Comment: Pues de igual manera no describe bien el query que ingresa a la terminal o no muestra su tabla con la descripcion de cada columna a la que quiere consultar, se necesita mas informacion para poder resolver el asunto del problema

Comment: Entonces la pregunta no se deberia contestar hasta que ocurra eso. Mira [answer] ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias.